# How to SUPPRESS "Unfortunately [app] has stopped" messages?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, crashes, oneplus-one, crash-reports

I'm not trying to fix this error for any particular app. I'm just trying to fully suppress it globally because it's completely useless and very distracting to me whenever it occurs.

How can I make my phone stop popping up "unfortunately [blah] has stopped" error messages whenever something crashes? (I have root permissions so I can edit anything necessary.)

Comment: Mehrdad, goto your all apps tab in settings->applications [or the like] and first goto the app in question settings and disable notifications. Reboot, i am guessing this is occurring at bootup? See if that remedies the the issue. Else, you need an app if there isn't an in-house function to micro-manage notifications. @Lucky is spot-on, check your logcat, it may show you a path to resolving the issue.

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments a bit, we'll accept it as a given that you don't want to uninstall the app and such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't (without customizing the code).  The relevant code is in the [Activity Manager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.0_r2/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java) (see `crashApplication()` and `handleAppCrashLocked()`) and it only suppresses these crash messages in 2 cases:

1. The app crashed too soon since the last crash
2. The app has crashed too many times total

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Matthew, you cannot change this behavior without rebuild the AOSP.

Apart from customizing `ActivityManagerService.java`, you can also change `AppErrorDialog.java`: this class implements the dialog and it's already designed to dismiss itself after a timeout, which is quite longer (5 min in Marshmallow). You can make it shorter by lowering `DISMISS_TIMEOUT`, e.g. to a few seconds, and have a less intrusive popup