# Cause and solution of "Error: Unknown operation string: <OP>"

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, system-error, command-line

First of all, the following command works perfectly fine on Android 5.1.1 (CM, PA and Tesla ROM builds):

```
adb shell su -c 'appops set android SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW deny'
```

The said command blocks Android System (`android`) to draw over other apps (show overlay).

The same command on execution in COS12 (Android 5.0.2) throws the command's usage and the error:

```
Error: Unknown operation string: SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

(<sub>SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW henceforth as <OP> here)</sub>

Per the info in the source code of [AppOpsManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.2_r1/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java#1070), the error should show up when `<OP>` is *null* which it is not in my opinion.

#### Series of failed attempts

- I tried with multiple types of operations with no avail, both in uppercase and lowercase characters.
- I also unsuccessfully tried with interactive shell session, that is, `adb shell` → `su` → command.
- I replaced single quotes with double quotes and also attempted with enclosing `<OP>` with double quotes.
- I hopelessly tried `android:system_alert_window` as `<OP>` too. Same goes for using `OP_<OP>` as `<OP>`.
- While I didn't need to change the SELinux status to Permissive in CM12.1, I did set it to Permissive and tried aforesaid steps with no success.
- Tried for a change: I thought [App Ops](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.findsdk.apppermission) by nowsky and [App Ops  [Root]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=droidmate.appopsinstaller) by Droid Mate might help but they simply showed what Privacy Guard of CM gives.
- I edited `/data/system/appops.xml` and reflected the changes found in the same file for CM12.1. Since I was not clear on what I was doing, it partially worked.
- There is the system service `appops` and I've no idea how to make good use of it.

So, what is wrong in my command and how do I make it work?

#### My original goal

The problem posted [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/115549/96277) can be solved by that first command in all of my Android 5.1.1 builds. (There may be side-effects of it.) Now I need to find a way to port my solution on Android 5.0.2 build.

**Note**: the device is OnePlus One.

**Update**: I've now tested the command on stock Android 5.0 (running on Nexus 6) and the situation remains same.

Comment: Okay, so I realized that something else is going on (it is not matching the received <OP> to null) in the line I linked about the source code.

Comment: Looks like it might possibly be that  
  SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW 

Is the wrong string for the API. Android 5.0 is API 21 and Android 5.1 is API 22. I am just curious but try 

 OPSTR_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Instead.

Comment: Nope, no effect.

Comment: Even then, does it actually totally prevent the Android System from drawing over other apps? It probably does what the string says it should do - prevent Android from showing alert dialogs.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Try it, you would come to know  that it does.